# Are pseudo-Anosov foliations dense?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, mapping-class-groups, teichmuller-theory

A pseudo-Anosov foliation of a compact orientable surface $F$ is a one whose class in the space $\mathcal{PMF}(F)$ of projective measured foliations is preserved by some pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism of $F$. I saw it casually mentioned that pseudo-Anosov foliations are dense in $\mathcal{PMF}(F)$. What is a proper reference for that result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pseudo-Anosov foliations form a subset of $\mathcal{PMF}(F)$ which is invariant under the action of the mapping class group $MCG(F)$, because if $\Lambda_+(\phi) \in \mathcal{PMF}(F)$ is the stable lamination of a pseudo-Anosov $\phi \in MCG(F)$ then $\psi(\Lambda_+(\phi)) = \Lambda_+(\psi\phi\psi^{-1})$ is the stable lamination of the pseudo-Anosov $\psi\phi\psi^{-1}$.

So the fact that the pseudo-Anosov foliations are dense is an immediate corollary of Theorem 6.1 from "[Thurston's Work on Surfaces](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/9494.html)" (originally published in 1979 as "Travaux de Thurston sur les Surfaces"):

> The action of $MCG(F)$ on $\mathcal{PMF}(F)$ is minimal, meaning that every orbit is dense.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this was known earlier (check Ivanov's book, most likely, it is there), but you can refer to the following theorem of Lindenstraus and Mirzakhani (see their paper [Ergodic theory of the space of measured laminations](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~elon/Publications/measured_laminations.pdf)):

Let $\mu$ be a nonzero measured lamination on a hyperbolic surface $S$ whose support contains no closed geodesics. Then the $Mod(S)$-orbit of $\mu$ is dense in $ML(S)$.

Now, apply this to $\mu$ which is the stable lamination of a  pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism.

One can also show that in $PML(S)\times PLM(S)$ the subset of pairs $(\mu_+(h),\mu_-(h))$ is dense, where $\mu_\pm$ are stable/unstable laminations of $h\in Mod(S)$, which is pseudo-Anosov.